# How to extends properties of a widget and use in custom widget in flutter

Tags: react-native, flutter

How can I create widget that contain all properties of a another widget.

e.g. in react-native I can create interface that extends `ButtonProps`;

Here I can pass all `ButtonProps` properties to my `ButtonComponent`.

```
interface ButtonComponentProps extends ButtonProps {
  isError: boolean;
}

function ButtonComponent({isError, ...props}: ButtonComponentProps) {
  return (
    <Button color={isError ? 'red' : 'blue'} {...props}  />
  )
}
```

How can I do something like this in flutter?

e.g. I want to create *screen_wrapper* widget that contains all properties of `scaffold` class:

```
class ScreenContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final Color statusbarcolor;
  final Brightness statusBarIconBrightness;
  final bool safeArea;
  final Color bgColor;
  final bool withScaffold;
  final bool loading;
  ScreenContainer({
    @required this.child,
    this.withScaffold = true,
    this.statusbarcolor,
    this.statusBarIconBrightness,
    this.safeArea = true,
    this.loading = false,
    this.bgColor = Colors.white,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Widget widget = TabDetector(
      child: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: safeArea ? MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top : 0),
        child: child,
      ),
    );
    return AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
      value: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarColor: statusbarcolor ?? Colors.white,
        statusBarIconBrightness: statusBarIconBrightness ?? Brightness.light,
      ),
      child: Scaffold(
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                body: widget,
                // pass other scaffold properties here
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

and then use it:

```
ScreenContainer(
  appbar: Appbar(),
  child: Text('hello'),
);
```

Comment: I still don't get your question completely, what is the problem in using `ScreenContainer` with the same code?

Comment: so you have to duplicate all the params that `Scaffold` accepts, for example: see [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/ce40de69b7/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app.dart#L749) on how `MaterialApp` uses `WidgestApp` when building its `Widget`

Comment: @Alok I want to create a widget that has all properties that `Scaffold` class has. without redefine. and then use my custom widget.

Comment: @pskink so I have to redefine them in my custom class ?

Comment: yes, you have to do that, in the code i posted almost everywhere they use: `xxx: widget.xxx`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your situation right, then what you can do is, make a `StatlessWidget` having all the properties, and then just accept the child to be passed

```
class YourClass extends StatelessWidget{
  final Widget child;

  YourClass({Key key, this.child}): super(key:key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // have all your properties and then the child
      body: this.child
    );
  }
}
```

**Use it like this**

```
class AnotherClass extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // using your class
    return YourClass(
      child: your_widget
    );
  }
}
```

The above will have all the properties of the `YourClass`, then widget will be passed from `AnotherClass`. You can use `YourClass` anywhere, where you want the Scaffold properties like this only.

Comment: So I can't do what I have done in react-native, here in flutter?

Comment: From my experience, no @BeHappy That is how you make reusable snippets in flutter

Comment: Ok, tnx. I accept your answer if there is not any solution.

Comment: No problem @BeHappy I hope you get the perfect solution